# Meteor build does not build app with correct app ID

Tags: cordova, meteor

When I build meteor app with a mobile-config.js that has an App ID specified, it does not build the app using that ID. As a result, App gets generated using unique ID, which does not match with the server's App ID, and thus HCP does not work.

Build command is:

```sh
meteor build --directory /tmp --server https://somewhere.com
```

The mobile-config.js file is like this:

```js
App.info({
  **id: 'com.quranerkotha.app',**
  name: 'কুরআনের কথা ',
...
...
  version: '1.4.8'
});
```

I have logged the app ID at startup time in code:

```js
console.log("Application startup: " + __meteor_runtime_config__.appId);
```

I can see it is generating unique ID. For ex, I see `lk3awl936t0m.yz0kj2x9lpza` as the appID, not the appID specified in `mobile-config.js`.

Because of this, HCP fails with this exception:

```sh
com.meteor.webapp.WebAppException: appId in downloaded asset bundle does not match current appId. Make sure the server at https://somewhere.com/ is serving the right app.
```

Seeking help to fix the app id for the app.

Comment: why the ** at the start and end of "**id: 'com.quranerkotha.app',**"?

Comment: I was trying to make it appear bold. Please ignore that. in the json file, it is not there. Thanks for looking at this.